# CPP Macro: Counter that gives number of instantiations/calls

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I want to have a **C** preprocessor macro that knows the number of instantiations/macro calls of this macro so far.
Example:

```
int main() {
  printf("%d\n", MACRO());
  printf("%d\n", MACRO());
}
```

Should print

```
0
1
```

Is something like this possible?

Note that it is **not** enough to forward this to a function as proposed below.
It should work in the following context:

```
// global variable
std::vector<bool> calls_hit;

#define OTHER_MACRO() \
{ \
    const int counter = MACRO(); \
    calls_hit.resize(std::max(calls_hit.size(), counter)); \
    calls_hit[counter] = true; \
}
```

Comment: Removed the `C++` tag, since this doesn't seem to be C++.

Comment: Put the `C++` tag back in, since this now uses `std::vector<>`. `<sigh>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I happen to have a solution that is similar (in usage) to `__COUNTER__` , but is not limited to single counter - you can define many counters as you like.

This one uses gcc-specific feature, but should be able to do similar in other toolchain.

```
static int getpos(int lineno); // forward declaration

#define MY_COUNTER ({                                                    \
            static const int mark __attribute__((LSEG,used)) = __LINE__; \
            getpos(__LINE__);                                            \
})

static int __attribute__((noinline)) getpos(int lineno) {
    static const int mark __attribute__((LSEG,used)) = __LINE__;
    const int *p = &mark;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; *p++ != lineno; i++);
    return i;
}
```

In above code, LSEG expands to something like section(".rodata.line01234") generated from  `__LINE__` information.

Here's an expalanation of how this works:

1. Whenever you use MY_COUNTER macro, it is replaced with 2 code fragments: 1) code that pushes `__LINE__` value to memory segment specified by LSEG macro, and 2) code that calls getpos(`__LINE__`) function, which returns # of calls written up to given line.
2. LSEG macro expands to section specifier with a line number (ex: section(".rodata.line01234")).
3. By specifying linker to sort segment alphabetically (-Wl,--sort-segment=name with GNU ld), you can be sure all appended `__LINE__` values are in order they were used.
4. At run-time, getpos(`__LINE__`) function scans through the memory segment, and returns # of calls written up to given line.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Where does the definition of `LSEG` come from? A quick google reveals nothing.

Comment: I omitted definition of LSEG as that definition itself is a complex code to explain. I currently have problem editing

Comment: It's something like

#define STR_(s) #s
#define STR(s) STR_(s)
#define EVAL(func, ...) func(__VA_ARGS__)
#define LSEG_(n) section(STR(.rodata.line##n))
#define LSEG EVAL(LSEG_, ALIGN_DIGIT(__LINE__))

and definition of ALIGN_DIGIT is way too long to include it here because I hacked it up by defining

#define ALIGN_DIGIT_1 00001
#define ALIGN_DIGIT_2 00002
....
#define ALIGN_DIGIT_65536 65536

This was the only way I found because GNU ld only sorts sections in non-numeric dictionary order.

NOTE: I'm just did this for a fun. Macro like this should never go into real-world code...

Answer (score 6):

Why must this be a macro? Anyway, you can just wrap a function with a static counter in a macro:

```
int count_calls() {
    static count = 0;
    return count++;
}

#define MACRO() count_calls()
```

Comment: @Andy: well then of course the count gets incremented as well.

Comment: No, this does not work. I want to have the number of calls at compile time.

Comment: @Manuel: if you want the number of calls at compile time you'll have to use something like `__COUNTER__` with a macro to wrap calls to the function your targeting, however, that means you can't use `__COUNTER__` for anything else...

Comment: @Manuel: can’t be done with macros. Template metaprogramming might be of help, but then you need to give more detail. In particular, my solution still works with the new code you’ve posted in the question; no compile-time knowledge is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with

```
// global variable
std::vector<bool> calls_hit;

inline void a_function_since_this_is_not_C_after_all()
{
  static unsigned int hits = 0;
  const int counter = hits++;
  calls_hit.resize(std::max(calls_hit.size(), counter));
  calls_hit[counter] = true;
}
```